# PyQt5: QtCore.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZdaPvm, version Qt_5 on Python3.8 Ubuntu22

Tags: pyqt5, shared-libraries, python-3.8, undefined-symbol

I'm tring to execute a program using package `qtpy`, but there is a `ImportError`. For intuitive, I wrote a simply `test.py`.

test.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION
from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION

print(PYQT_VERSION) 
print(QT_VERSION)
```

And the error is

```bash
ImportError: /home/malloc/anaconda3/envs/paddleseg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZdaPvm, version Qt_5
```

I don't know how to solve it, though I have tried lots of methods.

The Python version is 3.8, Ubuntu22.

Part of The command

`nm /home/malloc/anaconda3/envs/paddleseg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so | grep "U "` output for the `QtCore.abi3.so` is

```bash
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR14QVersionNumber@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR18QRegularExpression@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR4QUrl@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR5QDate@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR5QLine@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR5QRect@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR5QSize@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR5QTime@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR5QUuid@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR6QLineF@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR6QPoint@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR6QRectF@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR6QSizeF@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR7QLocale@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR7QPointF@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR7QRegExp@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR7QString@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR8QMargins@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR8QVariant@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR9QBitArray@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR9QDateTime@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR9QMarginsF@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamR9QTimeZone@@Qt_5
                 U _ZrsR11QDataStreamRN8QVariant4TypeE@@Qt_5
                 U __cxa_atexit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U __cxa_guard_acquire@@CXXABI_1.3
                 U __cxa_guard_release@@CXXABI_1.3
                 U __stack_chk_fail@@GLIBC_2.4
                 U free@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U memcmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14
                 U memmove@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U qVersion@@Qt_5
                 U qt_version_tag@@Qt_5.15
                 U strchr@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U strcmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U strlen@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U strncmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U toupper@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

And `ldconfig -p | grep Qt` is

```bash
libQt5X11Extras.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5X11Extras.so.5
    libQt5Xml.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5
    libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
    libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5
    libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5
    libQt5WebChannel.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WebChannel.so.5
    libQt5WaylandCompositor.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WaylandCompositor.so.5
    libQt5WaylandClient.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5WaylandClient.so.5
    libQt5TextToSpeech.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5TextToSpeech.so.5
    libQt5Svg.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so.5
    libQt5Sql.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5
    libQt5SerialPort.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5SerialPort.so.5
    libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5
    libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5
    libQt5QuickControls2.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickControls2.so.5
    libQt5Quick.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
    libQt5QmlWorkerScript.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QmlWorkerScript.so.5
    libQt5QmlModels.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QmlModels.so.5
    libQt5Qml.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5
    libQt5Positioning.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Positioning.so.5
    libQt5Network.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5
    libQt5Gui.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
    libQt5EglFsKmsSupport.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5EglFsKmsSupport.so.5
    libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5
    libQt5DBus.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
    libQt5Core.so.5 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 3.17.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
    libFcitx5Qt5WidgetsAddons.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFcitx5Qt5WidgetsAddons.so.2
    libFcitx5Qt5DBusAddons.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFcitx5Qt5DBusAddons.so.1
```

`pip list`

```bash
Package                Version
---------------------- ------------
albumentations         1.3.1
anyio                  4.0.0
astor                  0.8.1
Babel                  2.12.1
bce-python-sdk         0.8.90
blinker                1.6.2
certifi                2023.7.22
charset-normalizer     3.2.0
click                  8.1.7
contourpy              1.1.1
cycler                 0.11.0
Cython                 3.0.2
decorator              5.1.1
easydict               1.10
exceptiongroup         1.1.3
filelock               3.12.4
Flask                  2.3.3
flask-babel            3.1.0
fonttools              4.42.1
future                 0.18.3
h11                    0.14.0
httpcore               0.18.0
httpx                  0.25.0
idna                   3.4
imageio                2.31.3
importlib-metadata     6.8.0
importlib-resources    6.1.0
itsdangerous           2.1.2
Jinja2                 3.1.2
joblib                 1.3.2
kiwisolver             1.4.5
lazy_loader            0.3
MarkupSafe             2.1.3
matplotlib             3.7.3
networkx               3.1
numpy                  1.24.4
opencv-python          4.5.5.64
opencv-python-headless 4.8.0.76
opt-einsum             3.3.0
packaging              23.1
paddle-bfloat          0.1.7
paddlepaddle-gpu       2.5.1
paddleseg              2.8.0
pandas                 2.0.3
Pillow                 10.0.1
pip                    23.2.1
prettytable            3.9.0
protobuf               3.20.0
psutil                 5.9.5
pycryptodome           3.19.0
pyparsing              3.1.1
PyQt5                  5.13.0
PyQt5-sip              12.12.2
PyQtWebEngine          5.13.0
python-dateutil        2.8.2
python-dotenv          1.0.0
pytz                   2023.3.post1
PyWavelets             1.4.1
PyYAML                 6.0.1
QtPy                   2.4.0
qudida                 0.0.4
rarfile                4.1
requests               2.31.0
scikit-image           0.21.0
scikit-learn           1.3.1
scipy                  1.10.1
setuptools             68.0.0
shiboken2              5.15.2.1
shiboken6              6.5.2
six                    1.16.0
sniffio                1.3.0
threadpoolctl          3.2.0
tifffile               2023.7.10
tqdm                   4.66.1
typing_extensions      4.8.0
tzdata                 2023.3
urllib3                2.0.5
visualdl               2.5.3
wcwidth                0.2.6
Werkzeug               2.3.7
wget                   3.2
wheel                  0.38.4
zipp                   3.17.0
```

Please give me some suggestions. It would be appreciated!

---

I downgrade the `pyqt5` to 5.13.0 and get another error.

```bash
Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/malloc/anaconda3/envs/paddleseg/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/malloc/anaconda3/envs/paddleseg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/home/malloc/anaconda3/envs/paddleseg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/malloc/anaconda3/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5))
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/malloc/anaconda3/envs/paddleseg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/malloc/anaconda3/envs/paddleseg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/home/malloc/anaconda3/envs/paddleseg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/malloc/anaconda3/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5))"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
```

Comment: You say you're using `qtpy`, but your code does **not**. So, you either have a configuration/setup issue, or you're not providing an appropriate example code as reference. Modules as `qtpy` are just *shims* around other modules, and, most importantly, that module is based on Python bindings that can **never** work together. That error could be caused by that module alone due to an internal bug, but we cannot be sure about it. Still, based on your output, you have two completely different, unrelated and incompatible versions of Qt, since your PyQt is based on Qt5, while your PySide is on Qt6.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks a lot! I downgrade the `pyqt5` to 5.13.0, and got another error.

Comment: I've never used anaconda so I cannot really help you here, but it is possible that: your setup has some "leftovers" that may lead to issues (for instance, you removed PySide6, but you have both shiboken 2 and 6). Also, as said, you're saying that you are using qtpy, but your code does not, so either you are not actually using qtpy, or you didn't provide a valid [mre]. It will also help to have more detailed information about your configuration, for instance your OS, if you're using virtualization, etc.

Comment: Same here. Did you find the solution?